# How to fix "Python quit unexpectedly" when trying to install a module through pip install? Terminal Crashes with message "zsh: abort"

Tags: python, macos, terminal, pip, zsh

I think I broke my terminal. For some reason I am unable to use **pip install** to install anything on my Macbook Pro.

When I try to install such as

```
pip install Flask
```

I get

`zsh: abort     pip install Flask`

[image: image of error]

I've tried both on pip and pip, but I get the same error on both.

[image: python error]

Now I am unable to install any python module. I thought it was due to Bash -> zsh from Catalina update but when I changed it to Bash and tried the same, I get the same result.

Any idea how I can fix this? I am unable to do any python work due to needed modules unable to being install now

Comment: Do using `python -m pip install xx` works? I am not really sure of what can help you. Did you try reinstalling?

Comment: Yes. Now I'm getting"Abort trap: 6" every time I use pip. I am also getting "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'" error every time Terminal starts

Comment: Which python is zsh looking at?

Comment: @C.Nvs how can I check?

Answer (score 3):

setting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH before installing any packages with pip solved the issue for me:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2t/lib
```

*(adjust for a valid openssl path in your system)*

I found the solution in this [github issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7254).

Comment: Saved my day! My python starts "quit unexpectedly" after upgrading openssl, which takes down pip, too. I also suspect it's missing some env variables. Exporting `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` solves the unexpected quit, and saves a headache of reinstalling python plus all its packages.